# connected space of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ be a set of square matrices. Consider the subset $S$ of $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ where the absolute value of the eigenvalues of the matrices in the subset are $\le 2$. Is this subset necessarily a connected space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessarily connected, even path connected. Not only that, but it is contractible. To prove this, we construct a homotopy from the identity map on $S$ to the map that sends each matrix to the zero matrix. We will construct the map by $$f(A, t) = (1 - t)A,$$for $A \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$, $0 \le t \le 1$. As $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $f(A, t)$ continuously squeezes the space down to the zero matrix. To verify that this homotopy stays inside $S$ for all $t$, we just have to show that each eigenvalue $\lambda $ of $(1-t)A$ satisfies $|\lambda| \le 2$. However, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $(1-t)\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $(1-t)A$. Because $|\lambda| \le 2$, it is clear that $|(1-t)\lambda)| \le 2$, and thus $f(A, t)$ is a homotopy from the identity to a point. So $S$ is contractible, hence path connected, and hence connected.